# Django Tastypie hidden PK

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I am using the latest Tastypie and have hit a snag. I need to hide PKs so people can't see service growth. All models have a `UUIDField`. I am using the `detail_uri_name` field and it gives me uuid instead of ID/ PK for get requests, so all good so far.

The problem I have is when I go to `PUT` or `PATCH` to the `resource_uri`. It thinks it is a new resource as doesn't have ID and so I get duplicate key errors where it is trying to create a new record. Any ideas? Here is my resource.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
       detail_uri_name='uuid'
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'user'
       always_return_data = True
       authentication = SessionAuthentication() 
       authorization = Authorization()
       excludes=['id', 'password', 'created', 'approved', 'password_reset_code', 'password_reset_datetime']

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<uuid>[\w\.-]+)/$' % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name='api_dispatch_detail'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off just changing the model's pk to a random hash instead. [Here is an app](https://github.com/jbrendel/django-randomprimary) that does just that:

```
A new base class for Django models, which provides them with a better
and random looking primary key for the 'id' field.

This solves the problem of having predictable, sequentially numbered
primary keys for Django models.

Just use 'RandomPrimaryIdModel' as base class for your Django models.
They will then automatically get those new, random looking IDs.


The generated keys look similar to what you know from URL shorteners.
Here are some examples:

    Ada6z
    UFLX1
    Q68mf
    zjvsx3
    fDXshK
    VNuL0Lp
```